# can't add boost to cmake project on cygwin: Imported targets not available for Boost version

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cygwin

I have cygwin in c:\cygwin64 and boost_1_64_0 in /usr/src file. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(BOOST_HOME /usr/src/boost_1_64_0)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/src/boost_1_64_0/boost)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(spider)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
include_directories(boost ${BOOST_HOME})
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.64.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(spider ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(spider ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(spider Threads::Threads)
```

Clion starts cmake this way:

```
C:\Users\steve\.CLion2017.2\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\steve\Dropbox\Projects\cpp-spider\cmake-build-debug --target spider -- -j 1
```

I get this error:

```
CMake Warning at /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1842 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/cpp-spider
   used as include directory in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/cpp-spider
   used as include directory in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/cpp-spider

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/steve/Dropbox/Projects/cpp-spider/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [Makefile:176: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

How can I diagnose the reason of the problem? Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try this advice from the messages: "Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing Boost's headers."

Comment: My suggestion would be to use hunter for dependency management of boost etc. Never fails and you get the version of boost you demand, whether or not it's been built on the host system.
https://github.com/ruslo/hunter

Comment: The line number in the error does not match your example. Can you fix either the error message or the CMakeLists.txt? I guess it it the target_link_library line. The error occurs twice, so I guess both Boost libraries are missing? Hab you checked, that both libraries are there? Have you tried the latest CMake 3.9, just to be sure?